# Using Ajax with Wordpress to load Div without reloading page

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wordpress

I would like to be able to use the links of the left side of [this page](http://www.e-comstudio.com/e-comstudio/services/) to load the sections without reloading the page. I'm assuming using Ajax would work but do not know javascript well enough to implement it.

I tried using the Ajaxify your WP tutorial but it's not working with my links ([ajaxify tut](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/05/how-to-ajaxify-wordpress-theme.html))

Is there a simple way to achieve with a minimal amount of coding?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this tutorial ([ajax tutorial](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxcontent.htm)) and it worked. I overcomplicated it because it was wordpress and didn't think that method would work.

I added the javascript to the footer.php file. You can see the result here: [example](http://www.e-comstudio.com/e-comstudio/services)